# PFObject as MKAnnotation causes NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, parse-platform, mkannotation

I have a subclass of PFObject that conforms to MKAnnotation, which is working fine for adding annotations to a map view, and starting to drag annotations, but as soon as I stop dragging, the app crashes with the following exception:

```
NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Getter should take no arguments!
```

I've tracked the crash down to `[PFObject forwardInvocation]`, which leads to `[PFObjectSubclassingController _forwardGetterInvocation:forProperty:withObject:]`, but I can't figure out what's calling the forwardInvocation.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem found... I needed to declare a `setCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)newCoordinate` method in the custom class. Whoops.